# $u_{n+1}=u_n+ n^{-\alpha} u_n^{-1}$ asymptotic expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I am considering the following sequence with $u_1 > 0 $ and $\alpha > 0$ :
$$u_{n+1}=u_n+ \frac{1}{n^{\alpha} u_n}$$

i) I have proven that $(u_n)_n$ converges if and if only $ \alpha >1$. In this case, we write $l$ its limit.

ii) Now I am looking for an asymptotic expansion :

- for $u_n-l$ if the sequence converges
- for $u_n$ if the sequence diverges

As $u_{n+1}-u_1=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{ k^{\alpha} u_k}$, I was able to prove the condition of convergence.

iii) I believe that for a sequence $u_{n+1}= f(u_n,n)$, one should find an auxiliary sequence $\lambda_n$ and evaluate $\phi(\lambda_{n+1})-\phi(\lambda_n)$. I consider $v_n=u_n^2$ and try to evaluate $v_{n+1}-v_n$. It looks better but I didn't conclude.
More generally, how do I find the auxiliary sequence and $\phi$ ?

Many Thanks,

I made some progress with $v_n=u_n^2$ :

$\begin{align}
u_{n+1} &=u_n+ \frac{1}{n^{\alpha} u_n} \\
u_{n+1}^2&=u_n^2 + \frac{1}{n^{2 \alpha} u_n^2} + \frac{2}{n^ {\alpha}} \\
u_{n+1}^2 - u_n^2  &=   \frac{1}{ n^{2 \alpha} u_n^2} +   \frac{2}{  n ^\alpha }  \\
v_{n+1} -v_n &=\frac{1}{ n^{2 \alpha} v_n} + \frac{2}{n^ {\alpha}}
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$$ v_{n+1} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{ k^{2 \alpha} v_k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}  \frac{2}{k^ {\alpha}}$$

Comment: have you tried $u_{n+1}-u_n\approx du / dn $? Works usually great with difference equations of this texture...

Comment: Taking $u_n = A n^p$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$, $u_n = A n^p \ln^q n$ for $\alpha = 1$ and $u_n = l + A n^p$ for $\alpha > 1$ and applying the dominant balance method gives
$$u_n \sim \begin {cases}
\sqrt {\frac 2 {1 - \alpha}} \, n^{(1 - \alpha)/2} & 0 < \alpha < 1 \\
\sqrt {2 \ln n} & \alpha = 1 \\
l - \frac 1 {l (\alpha - 1) n^{\alpha - 1}} & \alpha > 1
\end {cases}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\alpha>1$ we know that $u_n\to L$ so that $u_n=L+o(1)$.

Since we also have

$$u_{n+1}=u_1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^\alpha u_k}$$

it follows that

$$L=u_1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^\alpha u_k}$$

and that the error is given by

\begin{align}L-u_n&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^\alpha u_k}\\&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^\alpha(L+o(1))}\\&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac{L^{-1}+o(1)}{k^\alpha}\\&=\frac1{\alpha Ln^{\alpha-1}}+o(n^{1-\alpha})\end{align}

and the asymptotic

$$u_n=L-\frac1{\alpha Ln^{\alpha-1}}+o(n^{1-\alpha})$$

For $\alpha=1$, assume the auxilliary $u_n\sim C[\ln(n)]^\beta$. For $u_{n+1}$ we get

$$C[\ln(n+1)]^\beta=C\left[\ln(n)+\frac1n+\mathcal O(n^{-2})\right]^\beta=C[\ln(n)]^\beta+\frac{\beta C}n[\ln(n)]^{\beta-1}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{[\ln(n)]^{\beta-1}}{n^2}\right)$$

and for $u_n+\frac1{nu_n}$ we get

$$C[\ln(n)]^\beta+\frac1{Cn}[\ln(n)]^{-\beta}$$

Equating coefficients and powers then gives us $\beta=\frac12$ and $C=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, hence

$$u_n\sim\sqrt{\frac{\ln(n)}2}$$

For $0<\alpha<1$, assume assume the auxilliary $u_n\sim Cn^\beta$. For $u_{n+1}$ we get

$$C(n+1)^\beta=Cn^\beta+\beta Cn^{\beta-1}+\mathcal O(n^{\beta-2})$$

For $u_n+\frac1{n^\alpha u_n}$ we get

$$Cn^\beta+\frac1Cn^{-(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Equating coefficients and powers then gives us $\beta=\frac{1-\alpha}2$ and $C=\sqrt{\frac2{1-\alpha}}$, hence

$$u_n\sim\sqrt{\frac{2n^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}}$$

Comment: Thank you so much.